# i can add folders in gitignore with [] names

Tags: github, gitignore, github-desktop

i can add folders in gitignore with [] names  i have folder wit this names

```
 [exampel] / [example2] / folder / file.lua
```

in github desktop when i want to gitignore this file
right click and gitignore this file
github add this to gitignore

```
+\[exampel\]/\[example2\]/folder /json/data.json
```

i want manually add  like **\folder
not work
all of then
i cant do anything on my folder have [] in names in gitignore

add folder to gitignore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a backslash before the square brackets to escape them. For example, to ignore the "example" folder with square brackets in its name, you can add the following line to your gitignore file:

```
\[example\]/
```

If you want to ignore all folders with square brackets in their names, you can use this:

```
*\[*/
```